# Export R data to csv

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I've read a .csv file into R, ran some code to edit it and now want to export this data frame as a .csv
This so I can read it into R again for some different editing. 
How do I do this the correct way (meaning clean code)

Answer (score 1):

`write.csv(dataframe,"~/Downloads/filename.csv", row.names = FALSE)`

Different computers use different directions for slashes (\or/)and on a mac, I typically have to do the "~/ " at the beginning for windows it is typically "C:"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is called `df`

```
write.csv(df, "specify_path_and_file_name.csv")
```